# Google Analytics not receiving data

Tags: ios, google-analytics, xcode6

I'm having problems with Google Analytics in my app. The website doesn't seem to be receiving any data, but the app seems to send it rightfully. I'm following this Ray Wenderlich tutorial, and the point where you run the app, there should be 1 visitor in the Real-Time Overview. It keeps saying 0.

My AppDelegate.m

```
[GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;
[GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 20;
[[[GAI sharedInstance] logger] setLogLevel:kGAILogLevelVerbose];
[[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"UA-********-2"];
```

My ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];-
    self.screenName = @"ScreenZero";
//more
}
```

My Console

```
2014-10-17 15:07:52.479 Wheels[25548:2342406] idfa class missing, won't collect idfa
2014-10-17 15:07:52.513 Wheels[25548:2342437] CoreData: warning: Unable to load class named 'GAIProperty' for entity 'GAIProperty'.  Class not found, using default NSManagedObject instead.
2014-10-17 15:07:52.923 Wheels[25548:2342406] INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.09 -[GAIReachabilityChecker reachabilityFlagsChanged:] (GAIReachabilityChecker.m:159): Reachability flags update: 0X000002
2014-10-17 15:07:52.962 Wheels[25548:2342437] CoreData: warning: Unable to load class named 'GAIHit' for entity 'GAIHit'.  Class not found, using default NSManagedObject instead.
2014-10-17 15:07:52.978 Wheels[25548:2342437] VERBOSE: GoogleAnalytics 3.09 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher persist:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:431): Saved hit: {
    parameters =     {
        "&_crc" = 0;
        "&_u" = ".etno";
        "&_v" = "mi3.0.9";
        "&a" = 730280959;
        "&aid" = "com.samvandamme.Wheels";
        "&an" = Wheels;
        "&av" = "0.1";
        "&cd" = ScreenZero;
        "&cid" = "7deb1f6d-3407-47e6-8303-7bc6305cd706";
        "&sr" = 1024x768;
        "&t" = appview;
        "&tid" = "UA-********-2";
        "&ul" = en;
        "&v" = 1;
        "&z" = 15854684929669144728;
        gaiVersion = "3.09";
    };
    timestamp = "2014-10-17 13:07:52 +0000";
}
2014-10-17 15:08:12.537 Wheels[25548:2342437] VERBOSE: GoogleAnalytics 3.09 -[GAIRequestBuilder requestGetUrl:payload:] (GAIRequestBuilder.m:195): building URLRequest for https://ssl.google-analytics.com/collect
2014-10-17 15:08:12.538 Wheels[25548:2342437] VERBOSE: GoogleAnalytics 3.09 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher dispatchWithCompletionHandler:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:536): Sending hit(s) GET: https://ssl.google-analytics.com/collect?av=0.1&a=730280959&cd=ScreenZero&t=appview&_crc=0&ul=en&_u=.etno&tid=UA-********-2&cid=7deb1f6d-3407-47e6-8303-7bc6305cd706&sr=1024x768&v=1&aid=com.samvandamme.Wheels&an=Wheels&_v=mi3.0.9&ht=1413551272962&qt=19574&z=15854684929669144728
2014-10-17 15:08:12.815 Wheels[25548:2342406] INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.09 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher didSendHits:response:data:error:completionHandler:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:161): Hit(s) dispatched: HTTP status 200
2014-10-17 15:08:12.816 Wheels[25548:2342437] INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.09 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher deleteHits:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:443): hit(s) Successfully dispatched
2014-10-17 15:08:12.821 Wheels[25548:2342437] INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.09 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher didSendHits:sendMore:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:174): 1 hit(s) sent
```

My Google Analytics
[image: Problem]

So nothing gets sent to GA. Any ideas?

Comment: Weird thing: I just checked Google Analytics, and my data started working. Even RealTime. No idea what was wrong cause I didn't make any adjustments... Send me a message with your foocode, I'll review it for any differences with mine.

Answer (score 1):

I am having a similar issue to the one you are having but I don't think it is related to missing libraries. It looks like your core data class might be missing. To fix this problem try importing the framework and let me know how it goes.

Try doing this:

```
Go to: Build Phases > Link Binary With Libraries > (Click the plus button) > Search for CoreData.Framework
```

Comment: I found this link: https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=486

Comment: It seems that the warnings are harmless and will be fixed on a future SDK version. This still doesn't explain why it isn't working. I will keep looking as I am trying to resolve my own issue.

Comment: So it turns out that analytics are working for me. It seems that I just had to browse the app a little bit. I do have these warnings but they don't seem to be breaking the tracking.

Comment: The `CoreData: warning: Unable to load class named 'GAIProperty' for entity 'GAIProperty'.  Class not found, using default NSManagedObject instead.` warnings don't do anything. I think it's this one: `INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.09 -[GAIReachabilityChecker reachabilityFlagsChanged:] (GAIReachabilityChecker.m:159): Reachability flags update: 0X000002`

Answer (score 1):

I was passing for that same problem, and for me I tried :

Google iOS SDK 3.12

```
-(void)setupGoogleAnalytics {
        //Start Google Analytics
        NSDictionary *appDefaults = @{kAllowTracking: @(YES)};
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:appDefaults];
        // User must be able to opt out of tracking
        [GAI sharedInstance].optOut =
        ![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:kAllowTracking];

        self.tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithName:@"App name"
                                                  trackingId:@"UA-XXXXX"];
        [self.tracker set:kGAIScreenName value:@"Begin"];

        [self.tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createScreenView] build]];
        // Optional: set Google Analytics dispatch interval to e.g. 20 seconds.
        [GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 20;
        // Optional: set Logger to VERBOSE for debug information.
        [[[GAI sharedInstance] logger] setLogLevel:kGAILogLevelVerbose];

        [[GAI sharedInstance] dispatch];


    }
```

With that block above, I could test the implementation running in GA Real Time page on device in debug mode. Maybe you have to wwait 30 secs or more, but worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution

If you have Xcode 6.1 with iOS SDK 8.1.
Then choose your Target an the Deployment **Target to 7.0**.
In the project the iOS Deployment **to 8.1**.

Than link the archives, please not with drag and drop. (libAdIdAccess.a and libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a)
Go to **target -> generals -> add frameworks** and add and copy the archives into your folder.
[Pic 1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8g28j6y6vgpl9lo/Bildschirmfoto%202014-10-29%20um%2021.16.12.png?dl=0)

Than in Build settings go to the other linker Flags and add **-ObjC**
[Pic 2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gxi1rhlgq65inp1/Bildschirmfoto%202014-10-29%20um%2021.18.53.png?dl=0)

and in the App Delegate add this in didFinishLaunching method for deactivate IDFA:

**id tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
tracker.allowIDFACollection = NO;**

This works for me and delete all errors and the GA received data.

Comment: allowIDFACollection = NO doesn't help.

Comment: sometimes is the analytics server slow. after a few hours the statics already look up. I have switch the TrackingId:@"UA-********-2"]; to another app from me that correct works. You can see that your code then works. I think it´s a analytics problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just set

```
[[GAI sharedInstance] setDryRun:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

This warning doesnt effect the GA process, you will still get data on your GA web portal.